# Querying at firebase not working with orderByChild/equalTo with a string child field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I really don't get this and, once more, am close to desperation dealing with firebase..

I have a list saved at a specific location: root/Chats/WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2

```
    "Chats" : {
    "Jc9dASQdabXiT0holYFDkeqCczK2" : {
      "-L18x_ytEW0vEh5PpMWt" : {
        "deleted" : false,
        "lastMessage" : "Yes, we can meet on thursday",
        "nick" : "Hugo",
        "uid" : "WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2",
        "userType" : 0
      }
    },
    "WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2" : {
      "-L18x_ys4_VF-zSDDk8J" : {
        "deleted" : false,
        "lastMessage" : "Yes, we can meet on thursday",
        "nick" : "SABINE",
        "uid" : "Jc9dASQdabXiT0holYFDkeqCczK2",
        "userType" : 1
      },
      "-L18x_z5trZFItxd08XI" : {
        "deleted" : false,
        "lastMessage" : "I´m fine, thanks, how are you?",
        "nick" : "Melanie",
        "uid" : "qTmcljT8YAYf2TpnxX1LCopdXde2",
        "userType" : 1
      }
    },
    "qTmcljT8YAYf2TpnxX1LCopdXde2" : {
      "-L18x_z5trZFItxd08XJ" : {
        "deleted" : false,
        "lastMessage" : "I´m fine, thanks, how are you?",
        "nick" : "Hugo",
        "uid" : "WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2",
        "userType" : 0
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to check if the list contains an entry with a specific uid with

```
rootRef.child("Chats").child("WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2")
.orderByChild("uid").equalTo("Jc9dASQdabXiT0holYFDkeqCczK2")
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent
```

Handler:

```
    rootRef.child("Chats").child("WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2")
                    .orderByChild("uid").equalTo("Jc9dASQdabXiT0holYFDkeqCczK2")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListenerAdapter(){
                        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot?) {

                        }
                    })

    open class ValueEventListenerAdapter : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot?) {}
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
        throw DbFailureException(if (error != null) error.message else "Unknown reason")
    }
}
```

The DataSnapShot object I receive in the onDataChange method is empty, nothing found. Why? It's working with the boolean fields, like .orderByChild("deleted").equalTo(false), just not with the string fields. Same situation with the other string fields.
Can also somebody please explain why this data querying at firebase is so ridiculously complicated and each query takes hours of research to find out how it has to be done?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: While further using the software and testing around, it even seems that this kind of code, also used in similar way at other places, sometimes works, giving the single value back, sometimes not. Really weird..

Comment: Can you show the content of your handler, so we can check **how** you're handling the query results? Even if you just log the data, that is fine; just make sure it reproduces the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to copy, I implement a ValueEventListener Object and have a look directly at the DataSnapshot that I receive at onDataChange before doing anything with it

Comment: Please share us the content of your handler.

Comment: I have shared it

Answer (score 0):

Just do

> rootRef.child("Chats")
>   .orderByChild("uid").equalTo("Jc9dASQdabXiT0holYFDkeqCczK2")
>   .addListenerForSingleValueEvent

This query, for all children in the "Chats" node, will order them by "uid", and returns the one with the right uid value.
 I think the query before did not work for you because you explicitly specify which child in chat using `.child("WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2")`, which returns you the child with the key "WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2" (which is one single chat object), so orderByChild("uid") does not work like it's supposed to anymore.

Comment: That doesn´t help, under every first level Uid I have an own list with elements that have a second level Uid. I need to take one specific list by going directly to it with specific first level Uid, and then search this list for the second level Uid. With .child("WPXEmqvX1BfQB9n3UQFjF3xi1so2") I do not get a single Chat object, I get a list

Answer (score 0):

When you are holding particular node you can't update the same node. Why because it's still in use and holding reference.