# Firebase database node compare and update

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Is it possible to query and update the same node at a time?
Am writes the query to find the node and in that same query if the node is available trying to remove the same node, while in this process node is removing, but again creates the same node with the previous value.

```
val query: Query = firebaseDatabase.reference.child("members").orderByChild("resetKey")
        .equalTo(uniqueKey)
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("snapshot", snapshot.value.toString())
                for (childSnap in snapshot.children) {
                 
                 val key= childSnap.child("resetKey").value.toString()
                    if (key.isNotEmpty() && key == uniqueKey) {
                   
                        firebaseDatabase.reference.child("members")
                        .child(childSnap.key!!)
                        .child("resetKey").removeValue()      
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("error", error.message.toString())
        }
    })
```

Comment: Why do you say "creates the same node with the previous value"? I cannot see any `setValue()` method call in your code.

Comment: While removing the key, key is again created in db. This is the issue facing.

Comment: Is there somewhere in the code a call to `setValue()`? If yes, add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

Here's an example

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ApplicationConfig/Steppers").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if("query")
                  {
                       it.ref.setValue("your value")
                   }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                
            }
        })
```

Query to use:

```
if (it.key == "YourKey"), if (it.value == "Your Value")
```

Remember to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: here am first checking for key and if the key is available, taking reference of the parent of this key and after that trying to remove the key. but here the key is removing and again the key is generating with the same value. (Used Koin DI and taking the single instance of firebase)

Comment: please add struture of database

Comment: Dbname- 
               -child1-
                          {"resetKey" = "xxxx"}                                          
               -child2-
                          {"resetKey" = "xxxxxxx"}                                                     
               -child3--
                          {"resetKey" = "xxxxxxxx"}.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963191/querying-at-firebase-not-working-with-orderbychild-equalto-with-a-string-child-f?rq=1

Comment: same problem here to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576761/firebase-orderbychild-and-equalto-is-not-working-properly?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

While holding the node, we cant update/remove the node value, but we can update child nodes.